# How to update a certain field?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 String statusOff= "off";
    Map<String, Object> status = new HashMap<>();
    status.put("status", statusOff);
    db.collection("Users").document("terapis")
        .update(status)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           }
```

The code is working but i have a problem, as you can see, i manually input the `document id`
I dont know any function like `whereEqualTo` for update.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to update all documents that match some condition, that's not possible.  There is no SQL-like "update where" functionality.   You will have to query for each of the documents that match your condition, iterate the results, then update each document individually.